# Error when calling oracle procedure with c#?

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I wrote this procedure in Oracle:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE P1 
(
   ID_1 IN NUMBER   
  , P_NAME OUT VARCHAR2  
) AS 
BEGIN
 -- INSERT INTO A1 (ID, NAME_) VALUES (ID_1,'6666');
  SELECT NAME_ into  p_name  FROM  A1 WHERE ID=ID_1; 
END P1;
```

And wrote this code in c# for run that procedure:

```
cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "P1";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("ID_1", 88);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_name", OracleType.VarChar, 16).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Console.WriteLine(cmd.Parameters["p_name"].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Connection.Close();
```

But when I run the c# app I get this error:

> ```
> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-06550: line 1
> , column 18:
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'P1'
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> ```

What happened?

Comment: `ParameterDirection.Output` not `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` You are also using `ExecuteNonQuery` with a Query (`SELECT`)

Comment: @AlexK. thanks you my friend it's work!,please post your solution to vote up your post.

Answer (score 1):

You need `ParameterDirection.Output` not `ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` for paramaters marked as `OUT`.

You are also using `ExecuteNonQuery` with a Query (`SELECT`)

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab in the dark here:

```
// this line looks wrong as it's not the return value, that's the return value of the procedure itself.
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_name", OracleType.VarChar, 16).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

// I think it should be ouput
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_name", OracleType.VarChar, 16).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```